# How to find particular dependency in pom.xml from jenkins job for a number of projects?

Tags: maven, jenkins, github, groovy

I need to scan all springboot projects from my github organization which uses a particular dependency(say platform-core) being used in pom.xml.

Need to create a freestyle/maven stand-alone job which should scan pom.xml of all 100 odd projects from github and prepare a list which project has the mentioned dependency. mvn:dependency-tree gives the list, but for 100 projects need to understand the scalability , since this may involve downloading each project, run mvn:dependency-tree and search through the console output?

Can anyone help is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for *public* repositories, GitHub has introduced a feature for [Listing the packages that a repository depends on](https://help.github.com/en/articles/listing-the-packages-that-a-repository-depends-on)

(meaning, *without* you cloning the repo and running  `mvn:dependency-tree`)

But there is no API I can see which would query that list remotely (beside **scraping** the page)

So cloning and running (possibly in parallel) remains the one avenue you have the most control.